# Returning the value of an identity column during/after SQL INSERT command

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

Using VS 2010, with ASP.NET, and .NET 3.0, and C#...

When I use a System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource and call its Insert() method to insert a new row, and that table has an identity column, I'd like my method to return the value of that column.

For example, in my SQL 2005 table, I've got:

- Customer.Id
- Customer.FirstName
- Customer.LastName

Where Customer.Id is an identity colum.

When I call my method InsertNewCustomerRecord( "John", "Smith" ), I'd like to be able to return the Customer.Id that gets automatically generated in the database.

Sorry for such a roughly posed question.  Let me know if I can add better detail. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.insert.aspx) method uses the [InsertCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.insertcommand.aspx) property...

So modify the InsertCommand to be either

```
INSERT Mytable (col1, col2) VALUES (@param1, @parame);SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Or (for SQL Server 2005+)

```
INSERT Mytable (col1, col2) OUTPUT INSERTED.IDCol VALUES (@param1, @param2);
```

Comment: What's the correct way to translate this to C# that sits within an ASP.NET page?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or higher, you can do this in a single statement by using the `OUTPUT` clause:

```
Create Table Foo    (
                    Id int not null identity(1,1)
                    , Name varchar(50) null
                    , ....
                    )

Insert Foo(Name)
    Output inserted.Id, inserted.Name
Select 'Foo'
Union All Select 'Bar'
....
```

If you are using SQL Server 2000, then you should use `SCOPE_IDENTITY` like so:

```
Insert Foo(Name)
Select 'Foo'

Select SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Notice that I can only do one Insert at a time using this method because we want to call `SCOPE_IDENTITY` immediately after the Insert statement.

If you are using a version prior to SQL Server 2000, then you want to use `@@IDENTITY`

```
Insert Foo(Name)
Select 'Foo'

Select @@Identity
```

The problem is that @@Identity will do funky things if you have triggers on the table.

**EDIT** You asked how to use this information in C#. You would use it just as if you called a SELECT query:

```
var connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
DataTable newData;

using ( var conn = new SqlConnection( connString ) )
{
    conn.Open();
    const string sql = "Insert Foo(Name) Output inserted.Id, inserted.Name Values(@Name)";
    using ( var cmd = new SqlCommand( sql, conn ) )
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", "bar");
        using ( var da = new SqlDataAdapter( cmd ) )
        {
            da.Fill( newData );
        }
    }
}
```

Here I am assuming you have in your configuration file a `connectionStrings` entry for MyConnectionStringName. In addition, you will need to add a reference to `System.Configuration` in order to use the `ConfigurationMananager` class. I did not check this code but it should be pretty close to what you need. In this case, I'm writing the query directly. There are other solutions such as using a DataSource control and setting the `SelectCommand`.

Comment: I don't know how to translate from raw T-SQL to something that I can use within a .cs page in an ASP.NET web application. Can you point me in the right direction for that?

Answer (score 3):

I would rather go with [SCOPE_IDENTITY (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx)

> SCOPE_IDENTITY and @@IDENTITY return
>   the last identity values that are
>   generated in any table in the current
>   session. However, SCOPE_IDENTITY
>   returns values inserted only within
>   the current scope; @@IDENTITY is not
>   limited to a specific scope.

Be aware that @@IDENTITY might not return what you expect

> For example, there are two tables, T1
>   and T2, and an INSERT trigger is
>   defined on T1. When a row is inserted
>   to T1, the trigger fires and inserts a
>   row in T2. This scenario illustrates
>   two scopes: the insert on T1, and the
>   insert on T2 by the trigger.
>
> Assuming that both T1 and T2 have
>   identity columns, @@IDENTITY and
>   SCOPE_IDENTITY will return different
>   values at the end of an INSERT
>   statement on T1. @@IDENTITY will
>   return the last identity column value
>   inserted across any scope in the
>   current session. This is the value
>   inserted in T2. SCOPE_IDENTITY() will
>   return the IDENTITY value inserted in
>   T1. This was the last insert that
>   occurred in the same scope. The
>   SCOPE_IDENTITY() function will return
>   the null value if the function is
>   invoked before any INSERT statements
>   into an identity column occur in the
>   scope.

Comment: Where would I start to call that via C#/ASP.NET? Thanks.